# Fix product images at front page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

How can I fix this issue and have all the images in same size?
The problem is only in the front page

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haver to put resize code in your list.phtml file

file path `app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your design}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Sample code

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135,150); ?>" width="135" height="150" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```